# How do preserve plain text formating in my return data in Angular2 using Observables

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

I have a working Observable that **needs to** return formatted Plain Text *(not JSON)*. When I pull the Endpoint in a browser the formatted Plain Text is displayed correctly. Is there a switch I can add to my Angular2 service to display the original white space & line breaks.

Example: from my **http.service.ts** file:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
       constructor(private http: Http) {}

   // Endpoing must set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header
   getPosts(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000')  //local testing web service
          .map(res => res.text().PreservePlainTextFormating());

   }
```

I apologise that this example is not a working one. I made up **.PreservePlainTextForrmating()** to describe what I'm trying to accomplish in code.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you try directly accessing response.body, without converting it with `text()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that I misunderstand your question but that's not related to Angular. If you add text to the DOM it's the browser that ignores whitepace. You can add the text to a `<pre>` tag whose purpose is to preserve the formatting

```
<pre [innerHTML]="someFieldThatContainsTest"></pre>
```

or, as @MarkRajcok kindly added,

```
<pre>{{someFieldThatContainsTest}}</pre>
```

Comment: Note that `<pre>{{someFieldThatContainsText}}</pre>` works too -- i.e., `innerHTML` isn't required.

Comment: The `<pre>` tag worked. Thanks, I've been away from Web design for too long :-)

Only problem now is the `<pre>` tag says "undefined" before I hit submit.

Comment: Just ensure `someFieldThatContainsText` is already defined before you get the response from the server. `someFieldThatContainsText:string : '';`